# How to submit the search data from parent component to the child component on button submit -- Angular

Tags: angular

I'm learning to implement code using Angular and was trying to implement the search functionality using two components, one for search and other for result.  The components are as below:

//Parent component

```
<div class="full-box">
    <input type="" name="" placeholder="text" [(ngModel)] = "searchText">
    <button (click)="getSearch()">Submit</button>
</div>
<div class="leftpannel"></div>
<div class="rightpannel">
    <app-content [searchData] = "searchText"></app-content>  --- child component
</div>
```

I just wanted to know what approach to use in this scenario.

Comment: You are binding the ngModel to searchText. You should use it in the getSearch() function and then pass the result to your child component as searchData. Instead of passing searchText inside it.

Comment: Use a service with Subject<string> to send and receive data between your parent and child components

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from parent to child you can use Input binding @Input()

You can look the documentation : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Yes i was trying to implement same ,but how can i pass the data on submit click

Comment: Set the search value inside a new variable on submit (inside getSearch()) and pass the data to the child :  <app-content [searchData] = "newVariable"></app-content>

Comment: because with ngModel, you pass the data for each changes no only on submit

Comment: wont that be unnecessary trip to component and back again to template